# How to combine two JSONArrays JAVA (special requirements below)

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a code snippet to combine two JSONArrays into one. Here it is,

```
for (i = 0; i < cityJArray.length(); i++) 
{
    resultsJArray.put(cityJArray.getJSONObject(i));
}
```

It works as it adds the second JSONArray (cityJArray) to the first (resultsJArray). But, my requirement is to add the second one to the first array of the first JSONArray (apologies for I'm not able to explain by words, but I will try to explain using codes down).

This is the JSONObject:

```
{"results": 
[{"id": 248, 
"name": "Alternatif Cibubur", 
"slug": "alternatif-cibubur", 
"status": "active", 
"city": 
    {"id": 11, 
    "name": "Depok", 
    "slug": "depok",
    }, 
"longitude": 106.900786}]}
```

I have already converted it into JSONArray because I have to separate the field 'city' and change its attribute names into 'city_id', 'city_name', 'city_slug'. Because they will create a duplicate as it's already an attribute at 'results' field (see the given JSONObject).

(Purpose: Create a .CSV file from JSONObject)

(Problem begins: When I try to seperate a field from the JSONObject to make it into different columns)

JSONArrays details:

resultsJArray:

```
[{"id": 248, 
"name": "Alternatif Cibubur", 
"slug": "alternatif-cibubur", 
"status": "active",  
"longitude": 106.900786}]
```

cityJArray:

```
[{"id": 11, 
"name": "Depok", 
"slug": "depok"
}]
```

**I want to add this two seperated JSONArrays into one like this** (below is the expected output)

```
[{"id": 248, 
"name": "Alternatif Cibubur", 
"slug": "alternatif-cibubur", 
"status": "active",
"longitude": 106.900786,
"city_id": 11, 
"city_name": "Depok", 
"city_slug": "depok"}]
```

Comment: As shown above, `resultsJArray` is actually a JSONObject (since it is enclosed within `{...}`, and it is not clear what `cityJArray` is (there is also a comma after `"slug": "depok",}` which seems incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, there's no comma after slug. I have edited it now. Actually, the JSONArray is enclosed with `[{.....}]`. My apologies for the mistakes.

Comment: Please update `resultsJArray` and `cityJArray` in your question above then so it is clear what type they are.

Comment: Ok sure Sir, I have updated both JSONArrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as required, I have noted both arrays as Strings initially then converted both to JSONArray.

```
String resultsString = "[{ 'id': 248, 'name': 'Alternatif Cibubur', 'slug': 'alternatif-cibubur', 'status': 'active', 'longitude': 106.900786 }]";
String cityString = "[{ 'id': 11, 'name': 'Depok', 'slug': 'depok' }]";

try
{
    //Convert String into JSONArray for both results and city.
    JSONArray resultsJArray = new JSONArray(resultsString);
    JSONArray cityJArray = new JSONArray(cityString);

    //Get the first and only JSONObject within each of the arrays.
    JSONObject resultsJObject = resultsJArray.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONObject cityJObject = cityJArray.getJSONObject(0);

    //Get the required values from the JSONObject within city.
    int city_id = cityJObject.getInt("id");
    String city_name = cityJObject.getString("name");
    String city_slug = cityJObject.getString("slug");

    //Put the values into the results JSONObject.
    resultsJObject.put("city_id", city_id);
    resultsJObject.put("city_name", city_name);
    resultsJObject.put("city_slug", city_slug);

    //Print to verify.
    System.out.println("Updated resultsJArray: " + resultsJArray);
}
catch (JSONException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it and update you soon.

Comment: I have tried the answer and its working fine after some editings. I have one more question that how I can convert the JSONObject `resultsJObject` into a new JSONArray (`JSONArray resultsJArrayFinal;`) ?

Comment: `JSONArray resultsJArrayFinal = new JSONArray();` followed by `resultsJArrayFinal.put(resultsJObject);`

Answer (score 0):

I use the package "com.alibaba.fastjson" , code as follow:

```
public static void CombinTest(){
    String a = "[{\"id\": 248, \n" +
            "\"name\": \"Alternatif Cibubur\", \n" +
            "\"slug\": \"alternatif-cibubur\", \n" +
            "\"status\": \"active\",  \n" +
            "\"longitude\": 106.900786}]";
    String b = "[{\"id\": 11, \n" +
            "\"name\": \"Depok\", \n" +
            "\"slug\": \"depok\"\n" +
            "}]";

    JSONArray resultObjArr = JSON.parseArray(a);
    JSONArray cityObjArr = JSON.parseArray(b);

            for (int i = 0; i < resultObjArr.size(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject city = cityObjArr.getJSONObject(i);
                Set<String> keys = city.keySet();
                if(keys.size()>0){
                    for(String key:keys){
                        resultObjArr.getJSONObject(i).put("city_"+key,city.get(key));
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println(JSON.toJSONString(resultObjArr));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir. I have a doubt regarding the code above, that is how can I parse the `JSONObject aObject` to the `JSONArray resultObjArr`  without getting the string 'results'? Because I have 2 JSONArrays and I already converted it into String. so the 'results' field name had gone and I cant parse the JSONObject by the `get()` string method. Can you suggest me if there is any way to rectify it?

Comment: i changed my code，As above , i used your 2 JSONArrays as init data